# unbound identifier and no #%top syntax transformer

Tags: macros, racket

I'm playing around with a fluent interface (for a pretty strange definition of fluent) so that I can learn about racket macros better, so I mocked up this code to play with.

```
#lang racket
(require racket/syntax)
(struct Person (name location))

(define-syntax what
  (syntax-rules (is)
    ((what is x thing) (what is x's thing))

    ((what is x quote-s thing)
     (let* ((x-str (~a (quote x)))
            (x-id (format-id #'x-id "~a" x-str))
            (thing-str (~a (quote thing)))
            (thing-proper-str (cadr (regexp-match #rx"(.*)\\?" thing-str)))
            (thing-id (format-id #'thing-id "Person-~a" thing-proper-str)))
       ((eval thing-id) (eval (syntax-e x-id)))))))

(define John (Person "John Luser" "Here"))
(what is John's name?)
```

Running this results in `John: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%top syntax transformer is bound in: John`. If I had to guess, I'd say that all the putzing around I do with identifiers and strings strips the symbol John of its binding, or that I'm evaling in the wrong environment, but I don't know how to fix either of those.

Answer (score 2):

Just to compare: here's what your macro looks like if you push most of the work off to the compile-time phase:

```
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax racket/format
                     racket/syntax))

(struct Person (name location))

(define-syntax (what stx)
  (syntax-case stx (is)
    ((what is x thing) 
     #'(what is x's thing))

    ((what is x quote-s thing)
     (let* ((thing-str (~a (syntax-e #'thing)))
            (thing-proper-str (cadr (regexp-match #rx"(.*)\\?" thing-str)))
            (thing-id (format-id stx "Person-~a" thing-proper-str)))
       #`(#,thing-id x)))))

(define John (Person "John Luser" "Here"))
(what is John's name?)
```

One thing to note is that we're doing `(require (for-syntax ...))` because we're using those libraries at compile-time, during the pre-processing of the program's source code.

Also, note that it's a little simpler because since we're not really doing any munging of the `x` being acted on, we can just keep that piece of syntax preserved in the outputted syntax.

---

If it helps, think about your experience in other languages.  If you're familiar with Java, consider what happens if you write the expression: `"hello " + "world"` somewhere in your program, and then compile the program.  Do you expect the Java compiler to produce bytecode that, when executed, constructs a `"hello "` string, a `"world"` string, and the string concatenation between the two?  Most would say "No, the compiler should rewrite that to just the `"hello world"` literal as a part of compilation".

This is *preprocessing*.   When you write macros in Racket, you are teaching Racket more of these preprocessing rules.

Here, let us try the following: we'll add a `cat` command that knows how to concatenate strings.  That is, let's bring that concatenation example to life.

Here's version one:

```
#lang racket

(define (cat x y)
  (string-append x y))

(define msg-head "hello ")
(define msg-tail " world")

(cat msg-head msg-tail)    
(cat "hiya " "world")
```

Now, we know that as a regular function, both uses of `cat` here reduce eventually down to calls to the `string-append` function.  The compiler isn't smart enough to know how to touch the second use of `cat`.

But what if we wanted to do the same sort of compiler rewrite rule: if the compiler sees up front that the source code is trying to `cat` two string literals, why not do that at compile-time, so that the emitted bytecode is better?

Well, let's do that.  Version two follows:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax (cat stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ x y)
     ;; At this point, the following code is being run by the _compiler_.
     (cond
       ;; If in the source code we're transforming, both x and y are
       ;; strings, we can do the concatenation at _compile time_.
       [(and (string? (syntax-e #'x))
             (string? (syntax-e #'y)))
        (let ([xy
               (string-append (syntax-e #'x) (syntax-e #'y))])
          ;; Once we have this string, we still need to emit it back as the
          ;; result of the rewrite.  We want to produce a piece of _syntax_
          ;; in place of the original stx.
          (datum->syntax stx xy))]

       [else
        ;; Otherwise, we want to produce a piece of syntax that looks like a
        ;; plain function call to string-append.
        (datum->syntax stx (list 'string-append #'x #'y))])]))

(define msg-head "hello ")
(define msg-tail " world")
(cat msg-head msg-tail)
(cat "hiya " "world")
```

Now the problem with this kind of transformations is one of observation: if we did this right, no one should be able to tell the difference!  :P  Otherwise, it would be a broken transformation.  So to see the difference more easily, press the **Macro Stepper** button on the DrRacket toolbar: it invokes the compiler, but shows you what transformations happen to your program right before it gets turned into bytecode.

Comment: I wish I could say this makes sense, but I have a very weak understanding of how quoting, unquoting, quasiquoting, etc work. I can see what you're doing up until the last line (and I ought to, considering I did a lot of it on my own), but I don't understand why this code is transformed at compile-time and my code was run-time, nor exactly how `#\`(#,thing-id x)` works

Comment: http://docs.racket-lang.org/continue/#(part._.Rendering_.H.T.M.L) gives a brief introduction to quasi-quoting for regular lists.  Think of them as a very lightweight string-templating language feature, except it can deal with structures rather than flat strings.  See http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/qq.html for a more comprehensive guide to them.

Comment: Run the Macro Stepper on your original example.  You should see immediately what the difference is.  There's a deliberate reason why I'm using `syntax-case` instead of `syntax-rules`: I want to be able to do computations at compile time, and `syntax-case` lets me do that.  `syntax-rules` is much more of a "replace the left side with the right side" pattern-matching sort of thing: you're not allowed to do any significant computation with `syntax-rules`.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, do I feel silly! Fixed it a few minutes after posting this by changing `((eval thing-id) (eval (syntax-e x-id)))` to just `((eval thing-id) (eval x-id))`

Comment: Note: the way you have the macro now, all of the computation is being done at runtime.  You normally want to push as much as you can into compile-time wherever it's appropriate.  Doing the term rewrite from `(what is John's name)` to `(Person-name John)` can be done at compile-time.  You'll want to look into a tutorial such as Greg Hendershott's Fear of Macros: http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/

Comment: The `eval` approach is also going to be fragile, since it will depend on a dynamic evaluation under an environment that you don't necessarily have good control over.  I think you'll get _different_ results across running this in DrRacket vs a textual REPL vs a standalone program.  It's also not taking advantage of the cool compile-time stuff you can do in Racket, so I'd recommend continuing to look into that part: try to avoid `eval` unless you have no other options.

Comment: @dyoo unfortunately metaprogramming can be so complex that I don't even know what my other options are, much less how they work and how to use them!

Comment: Have you read Greg Hendershott's Fear of Macros tutorial?  It might help in clarifying the particular brand of metaprogramming that the Racket macro system gives us.  http://greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros.  It's good!